# Handling text conversion between java and xml

Tags: java, xml, jsp, text, escaping

I have a webapp that allows a user to enter text into a textarea, and then press save.

The text is then saved to a database in an xml clob, and displayed back to the user via the webapp as html.

There a few a issues with special characters.

When saving from the text area to the xml, the following characters need to be escaped:
`& < > " '`

Newline characters will be saved to the xml correctly, however, when they are are displayed as html, the newlines don't have any effect.

Both of these issues can be resolved in the following way.

**Before saving as XML:**

```
//get string from text area
string = string.replaceAll("&", "&amp;"); 
string = string.replaceAll("<", "&lt;"); 
string = string.replaceAll(">", "&gt;"); 
string = string.replaceAll("\"", "&quot;");
string = string.replaceAll("\'", "&apos;");
```

**After taking text from xml:**

```
//get text from xml
string = string.replaceAll("\n", "<br/>");
```

This solution works fine for what I'm trying to achieve.

The question is, in the interests of not reinventing the wheel, or elegance, is there a better, or existing solution to this kind of problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're on the right track.  Generally when you create a JEE web application you put together a class that handles general conversions like this in a class named ServletUtilities.  In it you can have a static method you can call, say "filter", and pass it a String parameter.  So, you can have something like this:

```
public class ServletUtilities
{
  public static String filter(String input)
  {
     if(!hasSpecialChars(input))
     {
       StringBuffer filtered = new StringBuffer(input.length());
       char c;
       for(int i=0; i < input.length(); i++)
       {
         c = input.charAt(i);
         switch(c)
         {
           case '<' : filtered.append("&lt;");break;
           case '>' : filtered.append("&gt;");break;
           case '"' : filtered.append("&quot;");break;
           case '&' : filtered.append("&amp;");break;
           //This next one is optional for the new line
           case '\n' : filtered.append("<br>");break;
           default: filtered.append(c);
         }
       }
       return(filtered.toString()); 
     }
  }

  private static Boolean hasSpecialChars(String input)
  {
    boolean flag = false;

    if((input != null) && (input.length() > 0))
    {
       char c;
       for(int i=0; i < input.length(); i++)
       {
         c = input.charAt(i);
         switch(c)
         {
           case '<' : flag = true;break;
           case '>' : flag = true;break;
           case '"' : flag = true;break;
           case '&' : flag = true;break;
           //This next one is optional for the new line
           case '\n' : flag = true;break;
         }
       }
    }
    return flag;
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.